# Delete an image in the aloha-editor

Tags: aloha-editor

The [Aloha Editor](http://aloha-editor.org/) ships with an image plugin that enables users to edit images inline. However, i've not found a way to delete an image in the editor. I'm on a Mac, and i've tried:

- Press Backspace when the image is selected
- Press Backspace wehn the cursor is in front of the image

There's also no "delete image" button in the floating toolbar.

Has anyone found a way to delete an inline image?

Comment: we'll add this possibility.

for reference: https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/issues/513

Comment: Did you find a solution?  This is still happening, 6 months later.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue. On windows, I can delete an image by pressing the 'Del' key. However, I've used a `float:right` css to position the image automatically and  in this case I can not delete it anymore.

I have added the following workaround in my page. It makes possible to delete the image by double-clicking on it.

```
$(function() {
  $('.aloha img').live('dblclick', function(event) {
    if (confirm("Supprimer l'image?")) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).remove();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

This seems to works on firefox. However sometimes I can see the image to be magically restored. On Chrome this magic behavior happens every time.

I keep investigating and I'll keep you informed if I fix this problem in a clean way.

---

Update: this is now fixed in aloha-editor. If you select the image and clear the src field value. See https://github.com/alohaeditor/Aloha-Editor/issues/513

Comment: Hi @luc. Its must have been really long, but did you manage to fix the behaviour?

Comment: Thanks! I followed up your discussion on the link already, and decided to do the same double click to delete thing. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the image URL from the URL field that appears when you click on the inserted image. That makes the image disappear for me. Not very convenient though. :)